# unhandled promises rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-got

I can't resolve my unhandled promise rejection with this script. Promises and async funtion are all new to me. 
I should handle the rejection but don't know how that works.

Can someone help me?

```
const rawRequest = async (url, headers, data, timeout) => {
// Set custom User-Agent string
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Kraken Javascript API Client';

const options = { headers, timeout };

Object.assign(options, {
    method : 'POST',
    body   : qs.stringify(data),
});

const { body } = await got(url, options);
reject('reject');

const response = JSON.parse(body);

if(response.error && response.error.length) {
    const error = response.error
        .filter((e) => e.startsWith('E'))
        .map((e) => e.substr(1));

    if(!error.length) {
        throw new Error("Kraken API returned an unknown error");
    }

    throw new Error(error.join(', '));
}

return response;
};

//script
const response = rawRequest(url, headers, params, timeout);
console.log(response);
```

Comment: Some proper indentation in your code would help us to be able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

The result of async function is in your then. Call your rawRequest function like this (don't do response = rawRequest()):

```
//script
rawRequest(url, headers, params, timeout).then(res => {
//do something with your response
 console.log(res);
}).catch(e => {
//handle exception (rejection)
console.log(e);
})
```

Hope this helps!!!